# Vue.Js / Vuex - how to declare id of elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This is a simple shopping Cart
Actually, when we clic on items, it updated the total number in the Cart.

But i want now to make a better Cart: showing each items in the list. Like when we chose 2 croissiants, it adds 2 croissiants in the Cart.

**My problem is**, in this course, i didn't really learn how to make a Mutation dependings of the ID of the item. I'm looking for the syntax witch is sending the ID of the item where we clicked, to the store.

Here my my 3 files : (Store's "index", "Home" and it's children "MenuItem")

Store :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    restaurantName: 'Cafe with A Vue',
    shoppingCart: 0,
    croissiantNumber: 0,
    baguetteNumber: 0,
    eclairNumber: 0,
    simpleMenu: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Crossiant',
        image: {
          source: '/images/crossiant.jp',
          alt: 'A crossiant'
        },
        inStock: true,
        quantity: 1,
        price: 2.99
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'French Baguette',
        image: {
          source: '/images/french-baguette.jpe',
          alt: 'Four French Baguettes'
        },
        inStock: true,
        quantity: 1,
        price: 3.99
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Éclair',
        image: {
          source: '/images/eclair.jp',
          alt: 'Chocolate Éclair'
        },
        inStock: false,
        quantity: 1,
        price: 4.99
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    copyright: state => {
      const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()

      return `Copyright ${state.restaurantName} ${currentYear}`
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ITEMS_TO_SHOPPING_CART(state, amount) {
      state.shoppingCart += amount
    }
  },
  actions: {
    updateShoppingCart({ commit }, amount) {
      commit('ADD_ITEMS_TO_SHOPPING_CART', amount),
      commit('ADD_ITEM_TO_SHOPPING_CART', amount)
    }
  },
  modules: {}
})
```

Home :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ restaurantName }}</h1>
    <p class="description">
      Welcome to {{ restaurantName }}! We are known for our freshly baked bread
      and french pastries! Give you morning a warm start or treat yourself in
      the middle of the day. Our butter is imported from local farmers in
      France. Once you take your first bite, you will see why everyone can't get
      enough!
    </p>

    <section class="menu">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
      <MenuItem
        v-for="item in simpleMenu"
        :name="item.name"
        :image="item.image"
        :price="item.price"
        :quantity="item.quantity"
        :inStock="item.inStock"
        :key="item.name"
        :id="item.id"
      />
    </section>

    <div class="shopping-cart">
      <h2>Shopping Cart: {{ shoppingCart }} items</h2>
      <h2>Croissiant: {{ croissiantNumber }} items</h2>
      <h2 v-if="baguetteNumber">French Baguette: {{ baguetteNumber }} items</h2>
      <h2 v-if="eclairNumber">Eclair: {{ eclairNumber }}items</h2>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <p>{{ copyright }}</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import MenuItem from '../components/MenuItem'
import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    MenuItem
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      copyright: 'copyright'
    }),
    ...mapState({
      restaurantName: 'restaurantName',
      shoppingCart: 'shoppingCart',
      croissiantNumber: 'croissiantNumber',
      baguetteNumber: 'baguetteNumber',
      eclairNumber: 'eclairNumber',
      simpleMenu: 'simpleMenu'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

MenuItem :

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
import BaseButton from './BaseButton.vue'

export default {
  name: 'MenuItem',
  components: {
    BaseButton
  },
  props: {
    image: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    inStock: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      defaut: 1
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      onSale: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    generatedPrice() {
      if (this.onSale) {
        return (this.price * 0.9).toFixed(2)
      } else {
        return this.price
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['updateShoppingCart'])
  },
  beforeMount() {
    const today = new Date().getDate()

    if (today % 2 === 0) {
      this.onSale = true
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="menu-item">
    <img class="menu-item__image" :src="image.source" :alt="image.alt" />
    <div>
      <h3>{{ name }}</h3>
      <p>Price: {{ generatedPrice }} <span v-if="onSale">(10% off!)</span></p>
      <p v-if="inStock">In Stock</p>
      <p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
      <div>
        <label for="add-item-quantity">Quantity: {{ quantity }}</label>
        <input v-model.number="quantity" id="add-item-quantity" type="number" />
        <BaseButton @click="updateShoppingCart(quantity, id)" class="test">
          Add to shopping cart
        </BaseButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

So i want to update this value for example :

```
Croissiant: 0 items
```

[Website preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK8Ka.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass either object or array to your action to handle multiple parameters.

`@click="updateShoppingCart({quantity, id})"`

and then in store:

```
 ...
  actions: {
    updateShoppingCart({ commit }, {quantity, id}) {
      commit('ADD_ITEMS_TO_SHOPPING_CART', amount),

      //here you have id that you can map to item type
    }
  },
```

I would suggest having item type that is constant in `simpleMenu` and not depending on IDs.